# FFMPEG output video from stream of images

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I know how to use ffmpeg to covert image sequence to a video.

What I want to do is start converting images to video, **before I have all the images ready,** i.e. as soon as I start to output images, ffmpeg starts conversion, and stops when the images stop coming. Is there any way to achieve this?

Edit : I'm trying this in Android.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store video on sdcard, you should start with FFMpegFrameRecorder class from OpenCV for Android. You can google it easily. It will allow you to add single frames and create a video bit-by-bit.

If you need to keep your video in memory, you will have to write your own frame recorder, which is not that trivial, but doable and I can help you a bit.